# Magento 2 How to convert checkout "radio" shipping methods into "dropdown" shipping method?

Tags: checkout, magento2.3, shipping-methods

Magento 2 Checkout page -
How to convert checkout "radio" shipping methods into "dropdown" shipping method ?

Comment: You can take reference from free extension : https://www.iwdagency.com/extensions/one-step-page-checkout.html  demo link: https://demo.iwdextensions.com/opc-m2/onepage/

Comment: @FeedlayTechnologies or any other way like progrmatically ?